# Disable bottom notification bar

Tags: linux, debian, gnome

By default, there is a notification bar at the left bottom corner with an arrow to expand it, just above from the windows list. This is very annoying and I want to disable it. Some time ago, there was an extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/ that did the trick, but the development has stopped and is no longer supported. How can I disable it?

Here you can see what I mean:

[image: left bottom corner bar]

Comment: Are you sure the extension is not supported by your GNOME Shell version? It sounds like you're running a version that's even older than the extension (3.22?) because the tray hasn't _existed_ since 3.26.

Comment: Gnome version for stable Debian is 3.22 https://wiki.debian.org/Gnome

Comment: Yes, but if you have old GNOME, there's no problem if you use an apropriately old extension, is there?